# Knowing the status of a very long function (execution time) in another class

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2010

Currently I have a background thread whose doWork calls a function similar to below.

```
private void ThreadForAnalyzingReqFile_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) 
{
    AnotherClass.AVeryLongTimedFunction();
}
```

Now, the code shall wait until **AVeryLongTimedFunction()** in **AnotherClass** finishes (that may take about 1-2 minutes) While this happens, how do I know exactly what's happening? Is there any way I can be notified that function (in another class) finishes?

This thread is in my MainWindow class of WPF. I am using Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Read about progress bar, BackgroundWorker and notifications each n-seconds. There are already same questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this.  Two easy options:

(1) Create an event in your UI class such as `UpdateProgress`, and notify that event at meaningful intervals

Example:

```
    private void ThreadForAnalyzingReqFile_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        AnotherClass processor = new AnotherClass();
        processor.ProgressUpdate += new AnotherClass.ReallyLongProcessProgressHandler(this.Processor_ProgressUpdate);
        processor.AVeryLongTimedFunction();
    }

    private void Processor_ProgressUpdate(double percentComplete)
    {

        this.progressBar1.Invoke(new Action(delegate()
        {
            this.progressBar1.Value = (int)(100d*percentComplete); // Do all the ui thread updates here
        }));
    }
```

And in "AnotherClass"

```
public partial class AnotherClass
{
    public delegate void ReallyLongProcessProgressHandler(double percentComplete);

    public event ReallyLongProcessProgressHandler ProgressUpdate;

    private void UpdateProgress(double percent)
    {
        if (this.ProgressUpdate != null)
        {
            this.ProgressUpdate(percent);
        }
    }

    public void AVeryLongTimedFunction()
    {
        //Do something AWESOME
        List<Item> items = GetItemsToProcessFromSomewhere();
        for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i % 50)
            {
               this.UpdateProgress(((double)i) / ((double)items.Count)
            }
            //Process item
        }
    }
}
```

(2) Create a progress percentage field on `AnotherClass`.  Occasionally interrogate this in your UI on a timer.

Comment: Thanks Torres. I understood the option (2). But, how to create an event in my UI class and what do u mean by "notify that event at meaningful intervals" ?

Comment: Answer updated to clarify.  The only "change" I made is assumed AnotherClass didn't require the static call.  If this is the case, you can just pass in a delegate that does the same thing along w/ the call.

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass a callback function to your "VeryLongTimedFunction" and call that every time some kind of "progress" event happens, like each time 50 items are processed, or 20 iterations are made , or whatever is the case with your operation.

Answer (score 0):

As others hinted, there are multiple ways of achieving that, however the simplest seems to be just to use `BackgroundWorker` instead of a thread.

To indicate progress, simply set `WorkerSupportsCancellation` property to true and then invoke `worker.ReportProgress(percentage complete)` to indicate progress. For a completion notification use event notification, e.g.

```
worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(method_run_on_complete);
private void method_run_on_complete(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) { ... }
```

For more details see:

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/112547-using-the-backgroundworker-in-c%23/

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/28774446-144d-4716-bd1c-46f4bb26e016